# ScrollTop() Объект не возвращается на место

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка, animate

Почему #cart не возвращается на место, если я прокручиваю страницу на верх. Если вместо `.animate` Использую `.css` , то все выполняется, но сразу же выполняется `top: 80px;` и `right: -180px;`. Почему?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop()>1){
                $('#cart').animate({'top':'80px'}, 300);
                $('#cart').animate({'right':'-180px'}, 300);
            }else{
                $('#cart').animate({'top':'20px'}, 300);
                $('#cart').animate({'right':'20px'}, 300);
            }
        });
```

Вот пример работы всего этого: https://jsfiddle.net/rx70x315/

Comment: добавьте пример что бы он воспроизводился

Comment: Geyan, https://jsfiddle.net/rx70x315/ - вот

Comment: ответ вам дали уже -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит потому что событие `scroll` запускаеться при каждом изменении позиции скрола, что в вашем случае приводит к большому количеству запусков анимации, и стек вызовов получается большой и очередь к вашей анимации вверх доходит значитльно позже. Вы можете для примера немного проскролить вниз потом вверх и подождать, через время ваша анимация вверх выполнится. Чтобы избежать данного эфекта, нужно анимации заускать по одному разу.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop()>1 && $('#cart').hasClass("posbottom")===false){
                      $('#cart').addClass("posbottom");
                  $('#cart').animate({'top':'80px'}, 300);
                  $('#cart').animate({'right':'-180px'}, 300);

                        }else if($(window).scrollTop()==0 && $('#cart').hasClass("posbottom")===true){
                        $('#cart').removeClass("posbottom");
                        $('#cart').animate({'top':'20px'}, 300);
                $('#cart').animate({'right':'20px'}, 300,function(e){

                });
            }
        });
```

Вот код. https://jsfiddle.net/rx70x315/12/

Comment: уже сделал сам все)))